# Derived Class instantiates 2 objects of BASE Class

Tags: c#, linqpad

I have a basic query. I have a derived class which is empty. I notice that when I run the below pasted piece of code (runs in Linqpad), I end up with 4 objects of the BASE Class. My understanding is when we instantiate a derived class object , in absence of its own constructor, BASE Class constructor would be invoked , resulting in 1  instance of the derived class.

```
void Main()
{

  NestedS n1 = new NestedS();   
  NestedS n2 = new NestedS();    
  NestedS n3 = new NestedS(); 


}

public class Base1
{

private static readonly Base1 instance = new Base1();
private static int numInstance = 0;
private readonly object lock1 = new object();

public Base1()
{

 lock(lock1) 
 {
  numInstance.Dump("before");
  numInstance++;
  numInstance.Dump("here");
  }
}

}

public  class NestedS : Base1{

}
```

The code results in 4 instances of the derived class. Can someone explain to me the reason behind the same.

Update:
Sorry , rephrasing my query here, pasting output as well. From output , numInstance should have been initialized to 1 already before second instance is created, but it is still 0 at time of second instance creation :

````
before

0 


here

1 


before

0 


here

1 


before

1 


here

2 


before

2 


here

3 ```
````

Comment: You create 4 objects: `instance`, `n1`, `n2` and `n3` - so why would you expect to only have 1 object?

Comment: *"in absence of its own constructor, BASE Class constructor would be invoked"* - every derived class always has to invoke a constructor of its base class in order to ensure it has been correctly constructed. It doesn't matter whether your derived class provides a user-defined constructor or not

Comment: Try moving `private static int numInstance = 0;` before `private static readonly Base1 instance = new Base1();` - that seems to fix it, although I am not exactly sure why (and what the language standard has to say about it)

Comment: note: invoking a base constructor is **not** creating another object - the instance of the derived type *is* the (single) object

Comment: Thanks , sorry for typo . Have mentioned derived class instance later. But I am puzzled that why numInstance has not changed to 1 on consecutive call to create derived class instance after creating first object of Base class. (instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for your surprising output comes the lines

```
private static readonly Base1 instance = new Base1();
private static int numInstance = 0;
```

The language standard says about field initializers (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#variable-initializers) (emphasis mine)

> [...] when a class is initialized, all static fields in that class are first
>   initialized to their default values, and then the static field
>   initializers are executed in **textual order**

So your code first creates `instance`, which sets `numInstances` to 1 and *afterwards* executes the line `numInstance = 0;` "resetting" the field to `0`.

Changing the order of the declarations to

```
private static int numInstance = 0;
private static readonly Base1 instance = new Base1();
```

Produces the result you were expecting, as `numInstances` gets initialized to 0 (technically twice) first before you construct the first instance. Alternatively you could also just remove the initializer from `numInstances` as the default value for `int` is 0 anyway